# C++ regsvr gets stuck on function call in static const declaration

Tags: c++11

I created a header to store a bunch of common constants used throughout my project.  They look like this:

`static const double MY_CONST = FOO();`

The issue is that regsvr gets stuck in my new file.  After debugging into regsvr, it appears to get stuck on this line.  After killing the regsvr process, I can run the program and step through it.  However, this will obviously be an issue down the road since it will have to register successfully upon delivery.  I'd rather not have a bunch of `static const double` definitions in each of these files.  Is there a way to get around this?  An idea I had was a `#define` method that is a lambda that returns a `static const double`

`#define MY_CONST (double)[]({ static const double test = FOO(); return test; })`

However I can't seem to get that to work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `FOO()` do? Realize that you call it at DLL load time (I assume it's a DLL, since that's what `regsvr32` is used with) once for every source file that includes this header (since every source gets its own separate copy of `MY_CONST`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged into the `regsvr32` and it turns out that any function that requires a 'logged in' context, thus the DLL would freeze upon registration.  The workaround for this was to assign my constant as a preprocessor directive.

Answer: 
`#define MY_CONST FOO()`